# How to just get a result without OrderedDict in skfuzzy

Tags: python, csv, fuzzy

i have done process data with fuzzy with skfuzzy, i wanna get a result a save to csv file

```
#tipping.print_state()
print tipping.output

#masukan fuzzy
print "Masukan Hasil Fuzzy\n"
fuzzy_temp2 = tipping.output
print add_upload(number, number1, number2, number3, number4, number5, fuzzy_temp2)
```

the tipping fuzzy output have a number with result of fuzzy like this

OrderedDict([('karakteristik', 3.0)])

But when i save to csv the OrderedDict([('karakteristik', 3.0)]) is join to the csv and the result like this

14,Service System Transition,3.00,3.43,0.00,3.22,,OrderedDict([('karakteristik',, 3.0)]),

How can i just get a number of result to input to csv when i use skfuzzy?

Comment: What exactly is your desired output? Also, where's your CSV code?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ the csv code is not important because is can read and save, i wanna to make this output OrderedDict([('karakteristik',, 3.0)]) , so like this 3.0, just the number and finally i input to the csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given an `OrderedDict`:

```
o = OrderedDict([('karakteristik', 3.0)])
```

Use `.values` and convert the values to a list:

```
x = list(o.values())
print(x)
[3.0]
```

Extracting the first value is easy - just index it.

```
print(x[0])
3.0
```

Comment: What the meaning In and Out? i cant understand, i make a variable o or what?

Comment: @MisdanWijaya Those are my python terminal prompts. I removed them now so  it's easier for you to understand.